# My simple custom listview show wrong items, not working as intended. Can't see what is wrong

Tags: java, android, list, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8ZOc.png

However, i ran into a problem. When i create the list with my adapter, it is supposed to be a list of 8 items. However, it just shows the first 4 of these items in a random order two times. Do you see what is wrong with my code?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    String headers[];
    String image_urls[];

    List<MyMenuItem> menuItems;
    ListView mylistview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        menuItems = new ArrayList<MyMenuItem>();
        headers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.header_names);
        image_urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_urls);


        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            MyMenuItem item = new MyMenuItem(headers[i], image_urls[i]);
            menuItems.add(item);

        }

        mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, menuItems);
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

---

```
public class MyMenuItem {

    private String item_header;
    private String item_image_url;

    public MyMenuItem(String item_header, String item_image_url){
        this.item_header=item_header;
        this.item_image_url=item_image_url;
    }

    public String getItem_header(){
        return item_header;
    }

    public void setItem_header(String item_header){
        this.item_header=item_header;
    }

    public String getItem_image_url(){
        return item_image_url;
    }

    public void setItem_image_url(String item_image_url){
        this.item_image_url=item_image_url;
    }


}
```

---

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    List<MyMenuItem> menuItems;

    MenuAdapter(Context context, List<MyMenuItem> rowItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuItems = rowItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return menuItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return menuItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivMenu;
        TextView tvMenuHeader;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvMenuHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuHeader);
            holder.ivMenu = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuItem);

            MyMenuItem row_pos = menuItems.get(position);

            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(row_pos.getItem_image_url())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.empty)
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .into(holder.ivMenu);

            holder.tvMenuHeader.setText(row_pos.getItem_header());

            Log.e("Test", "headers:" + row_pos.getItem_header());

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the data only when the `convertView` is null.So when it is not null,list items are inflated with data of previous list items. `getView` should be something like this

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.tvMenuHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuHeader);
                holder.ivMenu = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuItem); 
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            MyMenuItem row_pos = menuItems.get(position);

                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(row_pos.getItem_image_url())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.empty)
                        .error(R.drawable.error)
                        .into(holder.ivMenu);

                holder.tvMenuHeader.setText(row_pos.getItem_header());

                Log.e("Test", "headers:" + row_pos.getItem_header());
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks. But is there any way to keep the items in menu even when they are out of screen? They disappear when they are out of screen and when scrolled back up, it downloads the items again.

Comment: Yeah..To optimize `ListView`, items are destroyed when they are no longer visible. But Picasso caches the images by default. So when you scroll back up, it won't downloads the imgaes. It just loads the images from cache memory. It is the right way to do it. Are you telling that images are not getting cached? Test it once. Scroll to the bottom of list, turn off the internet and then scroll to the top. It should load the images from cache.

Comment: Items are getting cached. However, for example there are 8 items. I scroll down to bottom. Then, when i scroll up to 4th item, it loads the first item and instantly moves to top of list, instead of continuing to scroll up to linearly.

Comment: Well that's strange. Can you post the code where you are setting the `adapter` to `ListView`. Are you calling the `notifydatasetchanged` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution

```
else {


       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       holder.tvMenuHeader.setText(row_pos.getItem_header());
    }
```

I also encountered this problem earlier and this one works for me.

Comment: shouldn't `holder.tvMenuHeader.setText` be outside the else loop?